# Need advice on deck posts that will have concrete poured around them

Tags: concrete, deck, post

I have a raised deck, attached to the side of my house on one side and held up by three posts on the other. Under each post is a small cement pad and the posts bracketed to those with a buffer piece of a dark green wood.

I am going to be having the entire under deck covered with a cement patio. The issue that I see is that with the downward slope from the house that the concrete is going to be about 6 inches above the bottom of the deck posts. I know this isn't a good thing.

Is there anything I can coat the bottom of the deck posts with to help with future rot? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: It's not cement around wood that causes rot. It is soil or clay with moisture around cement around wood that causes the problem.  Cement is permeable.  You should be okay with this but why not use sono tubes and only pour as high as you need....then put your concrete down

Comment: If the cement has not been poured, there are water repellent admixtures; or you could just get water-repelling concrete.

Comment: Posts treated and rated for ground-contact will last 20 years or more. If your patio is expected to last longer than that, why not pour concrete footings?

Comment: I am not sure that I was clear in the post above. The deck is already in place, with small concrete footings under each of the three posts. I am planning to have a patio poured under that deck, but that patio will be about 6 inches above the current footings. In other words, they will be buried by the new concrete and that new concrete will be around those existing posts. My concern (and maybe it's not even a concern -- i am not sure) is that water will seep in and collect where those posts are now sunk into the concrete that was poured.